# Distribution with Plasma 5, rolling or LTS, security, encryption, non-free options

Tags: security, distribution-choice, software-updates, plasma5

Can anyone name Linux distributions matching the following criteria:

1. Plasma 5 desktop
2. Rolling release, LTS strategy, or at least non-disruptive updates from one release to the next
3. Security updates at least as reliable and fast as they happen on Debian
4. Installation on encrypted filesystem (by the installer, not create LUKS device by hand, etc.)
5. Non-free drivers (e.g., WiFi, graphics card) installable from repositories (not download RPM/DEB/etc. and install by hand); extra repositories are fine for this
6. Similar to (5), a selection of non-free programs (at least Skype is required, Opera would be nice) available from repositories; extra repositories are fine for this

My results and assessments so far:

- Manjaro looks good, but I'm not 100% sure about (3).
- Netrunner rolling lacks (4), but that can be worked around by using Thus. But as for Manjaro, I'm not sure about (3).
- Kubuntu would have been great, but (2) is in doubt after recent developments.
- Netrunner main edition may be affected if Kubuntu is not continued. Moreover, if choosing the Plasma 5 version, I am not sure about (2).
- KaOS lacks (4). If that is fixed in the future, it may become an option.
- openSuSE Tumbleweed lacks (5), at least for my hardware (on a standard Dell laptop, WiFi and display were both not working out of the box, documentation says something about "the hard way" that has to be taken).
- Debian, Fedora, Korora lack (6). (Korora has lpf-skype, but I was not satisfied with that when I tried last time.)
- I am not sure about (2) for Fedora, Korora, and the non-rolling version of openSuSE. For the latter I am also not sure about (5).
- Mint and Ubuntu lack (1).